# How to plot single/multiple lines depending on values in a column with GNUPlot

Tags: graphics, plot, gnuplot, multiple-columns

I have a little problem using gnuplot. Here is my datafile:

```
From Time Packets Jitter  
127.0.0.1:53091 1 0 274  
127.0.0.1:53091 2 0 417  
127.0.0.1:53091 3 36 53  
127.0.0.1:53091 4 215 55  
127.0.0.1:53090 4 215 55  
127.0.0.1:53091 5 215 33  
127.0.0.1:53090 6 256 78
```

(I put that "time" for the test, but it will be replaced by a datetime after it works)

I want to draw two different graphics, with `Time` column in x axis on both, and `Packets` column (on a first graphic) & Jitter column (on a second graphic) in y axis. But, as you may have seen, I don't know how many different values from the `From` column I will have (minimum 1, but I don't know the maximum, the data file will be refresh and some values will be added each x seconds).
So my problem is that I want to make another 'line' each different `From` values on both graphics.
In fact, having the `From` value in title of lines (example : "127.0.0.1:53091").
I want to add that if it's possible to change column order.

I tried:

```
plot 'data.log' using 3:xtic(2) title 'Packets' with lines, \
     'data.log' using 4:xtic(2) title 'Jitter' with lines
```

But it's on the same graphic (I don't use multiplot yet, I tried to make the multiple lines works before).

Is it possible ? If it is, How can I plot this two graphics in gnuplot ?
If not, we can remove the `Jitter` graphic, and plot only the `Packets` column on a single graphic but with the different `From` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution relying on several standard tools that should be available on any standard Linux box, and mostly based on bash. Lets starts with the datafile you provide, **without the first line**.

**Step 1**: split data into one file per field 1 : `awk -f split.awk < data.log`, with the following in `split.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# erase previous files
BEGIN { system("rm file_*.dat"); }

# print each line in a specific file
 { print $0 >>( "file_" $1 ".dat") }
```

**Step 2**: duplicate first line of each produced datafile (because using one of the fields as title in gnuplot makes this line ignored when plotting):

```
for f in `ls file_*.dat`; do 
    head -n 1 $f > tmp.dat
    cat $f >> tmp.dat
    mv tmp.dat $f
done;
```

**Step 3**: generate a gnuplot script that holds a `plot` command that plots the different files (see full script below).

```
 echo "plot \\" >> plot.plt
 for f in `ls file_*.dat`; do 
     echo "   '$f' using 2:3 title columnheader(1) with linespoints lw 2, \\" >> plot.plt
done;
echo "    0 notitle" >> plot.plt
```

FIY, the last "0" plot is there only because to plot several files onto a single plot, gnuplot needs a trailing backslash at the end of the line. And if there is one, and nothing to plot at the following line, an error is generated. So I could only find this dumb trick to make it work...

**Step 4**: call the generated gnuplot script.

With the data you provided, the script below ends up as:
[image]

Probably could have been shorter, but I like to keep things readable.

Full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1 - split data into one file per field 1
awk -f split.awk < data.log

# 2 - duplicate first line (useful for gnuplot)
for f in `ls file_*.dat`; do 
    head -n 1 $f > tmp.dat
    cat $f >> tmp.dat
    mv tmp.dat $f
done;

# 3 - generate gnuplot script
echo "set terminal pngcairo size 800,500" > plot.plt
echo "set output 'b.png'" >> plot.plt
echo "set multiplot layout 1,2" >> plot.plt

echo "set title 'Packets'" >> plot.plt
echo "plot \\" >> plot.plt
for f in `ls file_*.dat`; do 
    echo "   '$f' using 2:3 title columnheader(1) with linespoints lw 2, \\" >> plot.plt
done;
echo "    0 notitle" >> plot.plt

echo "set title 'Jitter'" >> plot.plt
echo "plot \\" >> plot.plt
for f in `ls file_*.dat`; do 
    echo "   '$f' using 2:4 title columnheader(1) with linespoints lw 2, \\" >> plot.plt
done;
echo "    0 notitle" >> plot.plt

echo "unset multiplot" >> plot.plt

# 4 - call gnuplot script
gnuplot plot.plt
```

Comment: Waiting for your help, I used this command:
  
`string commands << "cd '/tmp'\n"
                 << "set terminal X11\n";
                 << "set multiplot layout 1,2\n"
                 << "set title ' Packets Lost '\n"
                 << "plot \"< tail -n +3 gstServer.log | sort -t\\\" \\\" -k 1,1 -k 2,2n | awk -F \\\" \\\" '{ if (x != $1 && x != NULL) print \\\"\\\\n\\\"$0; else print; };{x=$1}'\" using 2:3 notitle with lines\n"
                 << "set autoscale x\n"
  ... Same with Jitter but not enough place in comment
 << "unset multiplot\n";`

But that was not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: So, Thanks a lot for your help, it might be very useful for my work.
I will try to make this script in C++, but with the popen command it might be quite easy.
Another time, thank you for you time spending to solve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution, which doesn't need external files. First I extract all the different sources in the first column and store them in a gnuplot variable:

```
filename = 'data.log'
from=system('tail -n +2 '.filename. '| cut -f 1 -d " " | sort | uniq')
```

For the filtering during plotting I use `awk` and define a gnuplot function

```
select_source(w) = sprintf('< awk ''{if ($1 == "%s") print }'' %s', w, filename)
```

Now you can iterate over all source stored in `from`. The complete gnuplot script is as follows:

```
filename = 'data.log'
from=system('tail -n +2 '.filename. '| cut -f 1 -d " " | sort | uniq')
select_source(w) = sprintf('< awk ''{if ($1 == "%s") print }'' %s', w, filename)

set style data linespoints
set multiplot layout 1,2

set title 'Packets'
plot for [f in from] select_source(f) using 2:3 title f

set title 'Jitter'
plot for [f in from] select_source(f) using 2:4 title f

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you for your response too.
Now I have the choice to choose which script is better for my using (and put this script in C++ might be easy too).

Comment: Very nice, the idea of doing it (almost) all using only gnuplot is interesting, your solution also avoids my `plot 0` command.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand your problem, but at least I can answer `How can I plot this two graphics in gnuplot ?`:

```
set multiplot layout 1,2
plot 'data.log' using 3:xtic(2) title 'Packets' with lines
plot 'data.log' using 4:xtic(2) title 'Jitter' with lines
unset multiplot
```

Will produce this:

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response.
This is what I want to do, but, as you can see on my "sample" data, there might be different IP and different port, but I don't know how many different IP:Port there can be (here in my example there is two different ones : 127.0.0.1:53091 and 127.0.0.1:53090).
So my goal is to draw another line on each graphic every time there is another value in this field.
Is it more clear or not really ? Sorry if not.

Comment: I see. The problem indeed is that each line on a plot must correspond to a `plot` command (or a "sequence" in a plotting command). So I think this would need some data pre-processing in order to separate the different adresses, then generate a plot command for each of these. Not that easy, but I'll think about it, probably some `awk` processing. And if you want to thank me, you can upvote the answer... ;-)

Comment: Oh, and a question: only two ports numbers? Or maybe several others? Because my above comment considered the assumption that there could be several others. If only two, then it will be simpler.

Comment: No, there might be one or more (two, three, I don't know the number) different IP:Port (IP and Port can change). On your multiplot, there is no difference from the first column (the is two 4 values on the x-axis for example, but the IP:Port is different). So yes, maybe an awk processing. Thanks to spend time on my problem. I have to add something : my goal is to replot this graphic each x seconds, and different IP:Port value(s) can be added or removed between two loop. (My reputation is under 15, so I can't upvote :( )