# How can I plot several charts from a set of sample data?

Tags: gnuplot

I've got a dataset that I'd like to generate a set of plots from, and I'm having trouble getting [gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnuplot/info) to do it.

I've got a dataset with the following columns:

- time (timestamp in ISO-8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`)
- client (hostname of the client; two distinct clients in the dataset)
- server (hostname of the server; eight distinct servers in the dataset)
- Two related stats, A1 and A2
- Two other related stats, B1 and B2

A given timestamp generally has a single sample in it. I have around 7000 rows in the dataset. Some example rows would look like:

```
time                | client   | server   | stat A1 | stat A2 | stat B1 | stat B2
--------------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+--------
2015-04-01T03:47:12 | client-x | server-1 | 12.2    | 20.0    |  2.3    |  7.0
2015-04-01T03:49:09 | client-y | server-6 | 15.0    | 25.2    | 10.0    | 15.2
```

I'd like to generate four plots, as line charts, one for every combination of related stats and client.

1. client-x and stats A1 and A2
2. client-x and stats B1 and B2
3. client-y and stats A1 and A2
4. client-y and stats B1 and B2

At this point, at at a complete loss as to how to approach this with gnuplot. I'm open to other options for generating the plot, but it needs to be scriptable as I get new/updated datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get line plots, you must do the data filtering outside of gnuplot, e.g. with `awk`:

First setup the time format with

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
```

Then extract all possible client name, unless you already know the possible client names:

```
clients = system("awk '!/^#/ { print $2 }' test.dat | sort | uniq")
```

and then plot the data using `multiplot`

```
set style data lines
set multiplot layout 2,2

do for [client in clients] {
    set title sprintf("client '%s'", client)
    plot sprintf('< grep ''\b%s\b'' test.dat', client) using 1:4 title "A1", '' using 1:5 title "A2"
    plot sprintf('< grep ''\b%s\b'' test.dat', client) using 1:6 title "B1", '' using 1:7 title "B2"
}
unset multiplot
```

The question is quite similar to [How to use one of the column of data as legend in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29823520/2604213).